# Make File Rules

Tags: makefile

I'm a bit confused how many RULES in total there are in this makefile:

```
edit : main.o kbd.o command.o display.o \
       insert.o search.o files.o utils.o
        cc -o edit main.o kbd.o command.o display.o \
                   insert.o search.o files.o utils.o

main.o : main.c defs.h
        cc -c main.c
kbd.o : kbd.c defs.h command.h
        cc -c kbd.c
command.o : command.c defs.h command.h
        cc -c command.c
display.o : display.c defs.h buffer.h
        cc -c display.c
insert.o : insert.c defs.h buffer.h
        cc -c insert.c
search.o : search.c defs.h buffer.h
        cc -c search.c
files.o : files.c defs.h buffer.h command.h
        cc -c files.c
utils.o : utils.c defs.h
        cc -c utils.c
clean :
        rm edit main.o kbd.o command.o display.o \
           insert.o search.o files.o utils.o
```

What I get from this is that there are 8 object files, 8 C source files and 3 header files. Would I just add those up to get the total number of rules in the Make File? Would it be 19 rules?

Hope someone can clarify this, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A [rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Rule-Introduction) in a Makefile is the things that looks like this:

```
target: deps
    actions
```

i.e. the thing that says what dependencies a target has, and how to build a target from its dependencies.

To know how many rules a Makefile contains, just count them. There are 10 in your example.

Comment: I am counting 11. How did you get 10? Thanks for your response.

Comment: How many `.o` rules do you have? And how many rules that are not `.o` rules?

Comment: I am counting 8 .o rules

Comment: 8 C source files, 3 header files.

Comment: Please read my answer. Rules are blocks that start with a target, list dependencies (optional) and give build instructions (also optional). You don't have a single rule that has a header as a target, do you?

Comment: Yeah, but I still don't see how you are deriving 10 rules from this. There are 8 blocks that start with the target (.o files). Can you please further explain, I am not seeing it yet.

Comment: What about the two other blocks that look like `foo: bar baz` followed by some instructions? Or just `thing:` followed by other instructions?

Comment: Oh! The 8 .o files , the edit target (executable) and the clean rule therefore 10 rules in total. Is this correct?

Comment: What do you think? Does it match the definition in my answer?

Comment: What needs further clarification?

Comment: So now there's another smaller part question referring to this makefile that asks what rules must be executed if command.h is modified. Would that just be kbd.o , command.o , and files.o ? Because the command.h dependencies all correspond with the targets I just mentioned. Please let me know if that is correct or not. Thanks again for your help Mat, greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you try it out to check your answer?

Comment: What do you mean try it out? I just wanted to know if I was correct or not... thanks.

Comment: Try it. Run that makefile, change the file you're told, see if what happens matches what you think

Comment: There is no specific file, it's a practice question in my software engineering textbook.. that's why I was asking if it was correct as there are no solutions in the textbook. Thanks..

Comment: @user3039950: So make some files and try it. If you're not willing to *try* something to find out whether it works, engineering is probably not your calling.

Comment: It isn't a course I'm taking, it's just a practice textbook for next year (elective). But you're being quite vague when you mean make some files. What do you mean make some files? What type of files? What do I insert in there?